# Why does the value not increase by 1?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use friend for unary operator overloading. 
However the value did not increase by 1 as its supposed to
Any reason ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Sample{
private:
    double x;
public:
    Sample()
    {
        /*No comment*/
    }
    ~Sample()
    {
        /*No comment*/
    }
    void setX(double recieveX)
    {
        x = recieveX;
    }
    double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

friend void operator++(Sample s1);
};

void operator++(Sample s1)
{
    s1.x++;
}

int main()
{
    class Sample s1;
    s1.setX(30);
    ++s1;
    cout << s1.getX();
    return 0;
}
```

The answer is supposed to be 31 and did work without friend.

Comment: You forgot to pass `Sample` by reference in your `operator++`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `operator++` takes its parameter by value. That is why it increments `x` on the copy.

You can fix this by taking parameter by reference:

```
void operator++(Sample &s1) {
    s1.x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to understand **passing parameters by value** and **passing parameters by reference** which are two fundamental concepts of using functions.

When **passing by value**, the function makes a local copy of the variable and its scope is restricted to the function only and any modifications made to it remain within this scope only and do not reflect outside.

As is in:

```
void operator++(Sample s1)
{
 s1.x++;
}
```

While, when **passing by reference**, the function makes a reference variable which is actually referring to the same passed variable and any modifications made to it will also be reflected outside of its scope.

As is in:

```
void operator++(Sample &s1)
{
 s1.x++;
}
```

The function call would however be unaffected and will still be:

```
++s1;
```